# How do I display main query posts in random order using add_filter

Tags: posts, wp-query, filters, the-content, pre-get-posts

So I tried **two** methods to simply display the main query posts in **random order** - simple. I'm also trying to understand all this better.

1. Using `the_content` add_filter, with my own instance of `WP_Query` class.
2. Using `pre_get_posts` add_filter.

I couldn't get the add_filter to randomize the posts. I also have to mention, Elementor plugin is used as page builder, so it's serving the blog page. Perhaps it's overriding my filter? Or I'm missing something.

Also, what would be the best method to do this, if my attempts below are not ideal?

My code with both methods as follows:

**FIRST METHOD:**

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'thefunction',10 ,1 );
function thefunction($content) {

    $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'orderby' => 'rand'
    );

    $mario_query = new  WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $mario_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $mario_query->have_posts() ) {
            $mario_query->the_post();
        }
    } else { echo 'error: no posts retrieved.'; }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $content;
}
```

**SECOND METHOD:**

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'thefunction');
function thefunction($content) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Not a query for an admin page.
        // It's the main query for a front end page of your site.
 
            // Let's change the query using arguments.
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );

    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: The second method should work, just change this line: `thefunction($content) {` into `thefunction($query) {` and it should work fine.

Comment: @admcfajn Thanks! It worked! Sometimes the little things get us :) You should post as a solution, so i can upvote you.

Comment: Just to mention, I renamed all the instances of the ```$content``` variable to ```$query```

Comment: Nah, don't worry about it. If I answer you won't be able to delete the question. Thank you though :) glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Should be add_action not add_filter when using pre_get_posts

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'thefunction');
function thefunction($query) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Not a query for an admin page.
        // It's the main query for a front end page of your site.
 
            // Let's change the query using arguments.
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );

    }

    return $query;
}
```